# AspNetCore 3.1: Handle exceptions thrown in the injected service´s constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, dependency-injection

The problem:
I have a simple scoped email sender service. This service relies on a configuration injected in the constructor.
If the expected  section is missing in the configuration file, the email service throws an exception in the constructor.

I can´t figure out a way to handle this exception without placing a IsConfigured flag inside the constructor´s service and refactor a bunch of code.

### the original code

```
...
// startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   //
   //
   // EmailService configured as a Scoped service
   services.AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>();
}

// service implementation
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly ILogger<EmailService> _logger;

    public EmailService(IConfiguration config, ILogger<EmailService> logger)
    {
        smtpHost = config["Email:SmtpHost"];
        smtpPort = Convert.ToInt32(config["Email:Port"]);

        //
        // if something unespected happens throws a exception here
        // (missing config file, smtpPort not a int)
        // some kind of exception is thrown
        //
    }            
}


// the method that consumes the email service never get called
// the exception is raised by the the dot net during the IEmailService injection
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail([FromForm] SendEmailModel vm, [FromServices] IEmailService email)
{
   // actual code
}
...
```

### Catching inside the constructor and IsConfigured flag

```
...
// service implementation
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    public bool IsConfigured { get; private set; }    // <-----------
    public EmailService(IConfiguration config, ILogger<EmailService> logger)
    {
        IsConfigured = false;
        try
        {
           smtpHost = config["Email:SmtpHost"];
           smtpPort = Convert.ToInt32(config["Email:Port"]);
           IsConfigured = true;   // <----------------
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // 
        }
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail([FromForm] SendEmailModel vm, [FromServices] IEmailService email)
{
   if (! email.IsConfigured)
      //handle
   }
}    
...
```

The question:
How gracefully handle this kind of exception without redirecting the user to an uggly catch-all-exceptions error page or refactor all my services implementing this IsConfigured flag?

Thanks!

Comment: What’s the exception? You can catch that particular type of exception.

Comment: I Believe this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Consider failing as early as possible. AT startup check for configuration and fail there. You should just pass the config value to the constructor and not have logic in there to extract it. At that stage it is already too late.

Comment: Can you show the email service constructor?

Comment: @Nkosi, I think you are right. Validate the config in the startup and fail fast there. Thanks.

Comment: See [options validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#options-validation).